# Retrieving Specific Field from Meteor Collection Document into JS file and strip HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, collections, meteor

I have a Meteor Collections called Projects. Each project has a title, and description.

I want to pull out the rich text data from the description field in my Template helper.

I am trying something like this to get the description for a specific project:

```
Template.projectItem.helpers({
    description: function () {
        descriptionHTML = Projects.findOne(this._id, {description: {}}); // Get description field for project
        descriptionString = descriptionHTML.text(); // Strip html tags
        return descriptionString; // return description string
    }
});
```

But it is not working. The reason I want to pull out the rich text data before having it render on the template is because I want to strip the data from HTML formatting tags before displaying it on the template.

1) How do I get the description field for a specific document in the collection only? I want to be able to access the description field from the js file.

2) One I get the description, how can I easily strip the html tags? Can I use jQuery on a string variable? Like

```
description.text();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## register template helper

register a global helper for your current Projects

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('project', function() {
    projectId = Session.get('projectId');
    return Projects.findOne( projectId );
});
```

In your template you can use

```
{{#with project}}
    {{description}}
{{/with}}
```

or

```
{{project.description}}
```

## update

#### 1. make a helper to clean your description.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('escapeContent', function(content){
    return _.escape(content);
});

{{escapeContent description}}
```

#### 2. make a helper return your escaped content

```
Template.postItem.description = function() {
    return _.escape(this.description)    
}
```

#### 3. or you can do it in transform, this part i write it in coffeescript

@Projects = new Meteor.Collection 'projects'

```
Projects._transform = (project) ->
    project.description = _.escape project.desscription
```

and you don't have to do it in template.

Comment: The description is already accessible like this. But I want to isolate the description in the js file before returning it to the template to strip the html tags... I updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I attempted this using your update 1 & 2 and I am close! Now the description is printing ...." &lt;font size=&quot;3&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; line-height: 14px; text-align: justify; &quot;&gt;Mauris ultrices porta leo sit amet vulputate. "            As you can see it still has some leftover html elements but no tags. How can I clear those too? Thanks so much I am getting closer.

Comment: It seems like _.escape will not remove the html tags, just convert them into the string counterpart. I want to remove the html tags all together. I am not sure how to do this...

Comment: It is working! Instead of using _.escape I used a strip function to get rid of the html tags. But the real help was using a handlebars register helper! I didn't know about that but it is soo useful. Thanks you so much crapthings! You really helped me out. You are awesome for this!

Answer (score 0):

Specifically what I did to solve this issue was add this into the template helper js file:

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}

Handlebars.registerHelper('stripContent', function(content){
    return strip(content);
});
```

Then in the template html file I used

```
{{stripContent description}}
```

Worked like magic! They key is using handlebars register helper which is extremely useful!